# .each being used in Rails app when only one result should exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why "each" appears in the third line because I think there is no other page which meet the condition

```
:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]
```

Could you tell me why?

```
  def friend
    if Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).exists? then
      Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).each do |f|
       f.destroy
       end
    else
       Friend.new({:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id =>params[:id].to_i}).save
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => params[:id]
  end
```

Comment: I would have refactored that to show the correct technique, and make it much simpler, but I can't figure out what it does. Why are you destroying a friend, if found, and otherwise creating a new friend but then throwing that one away?

Comment: Mr.Phlip, this code comes from the sample code from my text, which has a system that you can be friends with someone when you push a link and you can destroy the relationship when you push the link again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Active Record finder method `where` returns an array, even if there is only one element in it, so your either have to iterate through the array with `each` or if you know only one will returned, you could do something like use the `first` method, an example using the `first` method is:

```
def friend
  if Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).exists?
    Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).first.destroy
  else
    Friend.new({:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id =>params[:id].to_i}).save
  end
  redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => params[:id]
end
```

`Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).first` returns the first (and if you're correct), only object

Hope this helps

Comment: DRYing that code up would make the actual control flow more obvious. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right the `.each` is not needed. My Rails 2.3 provides `.destroy_all`, which returns what it destroyed:

```
def friend
  friend_params = { :member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id] }

  if Friend.destroy_all(friend_params).empty?
    Friend.new(friend_params).save
  end

  redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => params[:id]
end
```

So if you couldn't find a friend to destroy, add the friend.